# Obtaining twitter API timestamp from string ID

Tags: r, twitter, timestamp, tweetstream

Recently downloaded a small (230k) dataset of tweets using the streamR package in R. I saved the workspace, quit R and today began trying to use the information but the time stamp in ALL of the tweets (the created_at column of the data frame that streamR creates) shows the time when I restarted R and loaded the workspace... How can this be? Is the timestamp dynamic or dependent on the save of the file?

Being at this point, is there any way to call back a specific string_id and return the timestamp using streamR? I could create a loop and fix the issue this way, being that it is a information that is VERY time sensitive.

Comment: what kind of object did you save them in? What does the `dput()` of that object look like?

Comment: @MrFlick it's a data.frame! it's 51 columns, one of them with the created_at time in character

Comment: The class() of the column is "character"? There's no reason to expect a character value in a data.frame to change.

Comment: @MrFlick exactly! I'm not sure if I can find a workaround with the string id maybe even parsing directly from twitter...

Comment: Can you re-create the behavior? Save another small dataset in a workspace and reopen it to see if those values are reset as well? Are you sure you didn't accidentally run some command to update the values?

Comment: @MrFlick I just recreated it and everything works fine, I guess it could be some initial command on startup, I'm going to look into it...